Open uri as pop-up window
Some android apps open links in chrome preview tab, without adding it to main browser list, how can this be achieved? Regular intent just opens a full chrome window.

Try with CCT but. In this case Chrome must be installed in the user device.
Add dependency
dependencies {
   …
   implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.5.0'
}

Now with this library try out below
String url = "https://developers.android.com";
CustomTabsIntent intent = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
        .build();
intent.launchUrl(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse(url));


you can either use this plugin ' implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0'
' or  use 'web view'

WebView will not accomplish this.
